# How can use order-by in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, sql-order-by

I know this is simple but i didn't complete it.

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('prepared_forms', array('topic' => $this->input-    >post('prepared_topics')));
$new_form = $query->row_array();
```

How can order prepared forms order by topic name (ASC)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->db->select("*")
  ->from('prepared_forms')
  ->where('topic', $this->input->post('prepared_topics'))
  ->order_by('topic', 'asc')
  ->get()
  ->result_array();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$query = $this->db->order_by('topic', 'asc')->get_where('prepared_forms', array('topic' => $this->input->post('prepared_topics')));
$new_form = $query->row_array();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->db->order_by("topic", "asc"); 
$query = $this->db->get_where('prepared_forms', array('topic' => $this->input->post('prepared_topics')));
$new_form = $query->row_array();
```